# Sequelize Getter Method Date Format

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the getter method in my model to change the date format for my field to a mm/dd/yyy readable format, but it doesn't appear that my method is working or it might be that I'm not understanding how the method works. Below is my model and I try to expose the `annotationDateRead` field for use in a route, but I get an endless loop, which indicates that I can't find this field. Is there a better way to achieve what I am looking for?

model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Annotation = sequelize.define('annotation', {
    annotation_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    annotationDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'annotation_date'
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'user_id'
    }
},

 {
    freezeTableName: true,


    getterMethods: {
        annotationDateRead: function(){
            var date = new Date(this.getDataValue('annotationDate')); 
            var month = date.getMonth();
            var day = date.getDate();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

        }
    },

    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Annotation.belongsTo(db.User)
        }
    }
});
    return Annotation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work (version 5+):

```
getterMethods: {
    annotationDateRead() {
        var date = new Date(this.annotationDate);
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var year = date.getFullYear();

        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }
}
```